# ¿Cómo agregar el paquete de NuGet Json.NET en un proyecto de Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Lo que quiero es agregar el NuGet de [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) en un proyecto de *Visual Studio* ya que necesito parsear un *xml* a *json*, les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Usando el explorador de soluciones.

   Haces click derecho sobre el proyecto en el que lo quieres instalar y eliges administrar los paquetes NuGet desde el menú. Allí eliges el paquete de Newtonsoft.Json, que es de los primeros en aparecer listados (si no apareciera, tienes un buscador), y lo instalas.
2. Usando la consola de administración de paquetes.

   Vas al menú Herramientas, luego Administración de paquetes NuGet, y abres la consola. Allí eliges el proyecto por defecto en el cual se instalarán los paquetes desde el desplegable de arriba a la derecha, y ejecutas el comando para instalar el paquete en su última versión estable: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @gbellmann

Comment: Por nada, estamos para ayudar. No olvides votar las respuestas útiles y marcar la respuesta que te haya ayudado a resolver tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Mediante la Consola del Administrador de paquetes, debes ejecutar

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.1
```

Para obtener la librería Newtonsoft.Json que es por excelencia el paquete para tratar con objetos que deseas parsear o serializar a formato Json.

Más detalles en https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/